# Access index entry and subentry values with field commands

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

MS Word offers the capability of creating a list of acronyms using the index function in the references menu. I infer that at some level, Microsoft Word appears to use Fields to manage the entry and sub-entry of the index when defined and linked (i.e. entry definitions and placements with `{ XE "entry value:sub-entry value" }` and lists produced with `{ INDEX \c "2" \z "4105" }`).

On the way to potentially building a more comprehensive framework or approach, I'd like to find out whether, using a field command, is it possible to access the following components of a defined index entry:

- the entry values
- or sub-entry values

I.e I'd like to be able to put a field command like `{ flag "label for index entry" }` in the middle of a paragraph to access either the long or short form of an acronym.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you want to result from this? Why do you not simply use the fields either created by the relevant dialog boxes or manually created? Note, you cannot create your own fields in Word. You are limited to the collection that exists. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-in-word-HA102110133.aspx Fields can be nested.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - regarding your second sentence - I think this is the answer I'm hoping for, but don't have the working knowledge to extract.  My example is structured per my expectations of how a field seems to be structured, but I don't know how to access these. My question kind of assumes there is a field or trigger that would retrieve the entry or sub-entry textbox contents from this dialog box. My last paragraph was an example of what an in paragraph example should look like in field form.  I'm not sure what else I could provide to clarify examples for the use case.

Comment: The link I gave has the syntax for all fields in Word. This often takes some experimentation - trial and error - to figure out. Alt+F9 toggles viewing of field codes. Ctrl+F9 inserts an empty set of field delimiters { }. Here is my reference page on fields. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Very sorry for missing your link - looks like my ancient phone browser didn't show your whole comment. Turns out that I have seen this page before through. When I read it, and more specifically the index and xe subpage, I inferred that this is only applicable to managing the index list and formatting the definition. I did a bit of experimentation before posting, but there's always more that can be tried. Your reference page looks quite comprehensive, I'm going to start exploring it and see what I can learn and garner inspiration from for more trial and error. Thanks!